# Simple Grunt copy command not working

Tags: gruntjs

I know there is something very obvious that I'm missing but I just can't see it. I have this simply Grunt copy file that I'm running.

```
copy: {
        dev: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    src: [
                        "../index.html",
                        "../views/**",
                        "../scripts/**",
                        "../styles/**",
                        "../data/**",
                        "../images/**"
                    ],
                    dest: "../../iPhone/www/"
                }
            ]
        }

}
```

Everytime I run this my files go into the ../../iPhone folder instead of the ../../iPhone/www folder. I don't understand why it's copying one level up when I'm specifically saying to copy into the www folder. Again I know I'm missing something so trivial and small, but I just can't see it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just found something very interesting. If I add an arbitrary folder after www (i.e. ../../iPhone/www/assets) then it will correctly copy to the www folder since it's one level up from assets AND the assets folder is NOT created.

Comment: As you've found, grunt-copy will replicate the path while it is copying.  So, in this case, using `.../www` as a base, it will then traverse the path `../etc` and put the file there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The grunt copy command will, by default, replicate the path of the src into dest.

In this case, using `..` is the source (no pun intended) of your problem.

You can work around this by using the [`cwd` property](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

Your task config would look something like:

```
copy: {
    dev: {
        files: [{
            cwd: '../',
            expand: true,
            src: ["index.html",
                  "views/**", 
                  "scripts/**", 
                  "styles/**", 
                  "data/**", 
                  "images/**"],
            dest: "../../iPhone/www/"
        }]
    }
}
```